# using length and encoding with perl

Tags: perl

my mysql database is encoded ut8_generic_ci when i read some text field from the database using dbi
and store it on a $variable and run the lenght function on this variable i get a numeric lenght

```
  my $data retrive_text_from_db(); #using dbi
  print length $data;
```

but when i store the $data on a text file then try to read it on another script and run the length function i get sometimes different length

```
     open T, '<'  ,'file.txt' or die $!;
     binmode(T, ":utf8");
     my $text;
     {local $/; $text=<T>; }
     print length $text;
```

did someone experience this problem /could someone tell what could be the root of the problem and how can i solve it ?

Comment: Don't you need to `decode` before using calling `length`?

Comment: The slides from Mike Whittaker's talk on Perl and Unicode will probably help - http://www.slideshare.net/Penfold/perl-and-unicode

Answer (score 3):

Perl strings are either byte oriented or character oriented. I assume that the length reported by you first example always are greater or equal to the length reported by the second example?

When you use `binmode(T, ":utf8")` you tell Perl to take the stream of bytes in the file and automatically converts them into characters using the UTF-8 encoding. So in this example `$text` should be a character string.

My guess is that you have not configured DBI to perform this conversion and you therefore end up with a byte string containg the UTF-8 encoded data. Which means that some characters may require 2-4 bytes each. One option is to configure DBI to handle UTF-8 correctly. How to do this depends on the driver, as you uses MySQL it should work by connecting this way:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $passwrod, { mysql_enable_utf8 => 1 });
```

For some reason the default for this configuration variable seems to be off.

Alternatively you can do the conversion yourself with the Encode module:

```
use Encode;
$data = decode_utf8($data);
```

Comment: No the lenght reported on my first example is smaller or equal to the length reported on the second example

Comment: Its no matter to the DBI even when I run the following mysql query from the console i get the same result as the dbi  :            select length (data) from info where id=7

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try here is printing both `$data` and `$text` to the screen to see if they are the same.  If you have a character encoding problem, one of those will probably fail.  In that case, look into the [encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) module, as pmakholm suggested.

If that test succeeds, it is something more subtle.

One such possibility is that newlines are being stored differently between the input data and the text file. In some formats, newlines are one character; in others, they are two characters.  This would give you different lengths even though the data is effectively the same.